# AnsibleError: template error while templating string: expected token ':', got

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I have the following JSON file.

```
[
  {
    "NODE": "ha2(VRM02)",
    "ROLE": "active",
    "PHASE": "Actived",
    "RESS": "normal",
  },
  {
    "NODE": "ha1(VRM01)",
    "ROLE": "standby",
    "PHASE": "Deactived",
    "RESS": "normal",
  }
]
```

Through ansible I have it stored in a variable called "fusionquery1".
Through a template, I am trying to go through it to create a file with some data from the JSON file. Up to this part I don't get error.

```
{% for item in fusionquery1 %}
{% set item = fusionquery1[loop.index-1] %}
{{item.NODE}},NODE ROLE,NA,OK,cualitativo,igualA,ROLE,{{item.ROLE}}
{% endfor %}
```

My problem is when I want to add this conditional to the side of the above statement

```
{% if ({{item.NODE}} == "ha2(VRM02)" and {{item.ROLE}} == "active") or ({{item.NODE}} == "ha1(VRM01)" and {{item.ROLE}} == "standby") %}Ok{% else %}Failed{% endif %}
```

I get the following error

```
FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "AnsibleError: template error while templating string: expected token ':', got '}'. String: {% for item in fusionquery1 %}\r\n{% set item = fusionquery1[loop.index-1] %}\r\n{{item.NODE}},NODE ROLE,NA,OK,cualitativo,igualA,ROLE,{{item.ROLE}},{% if ({{item.NODE}} == \"ha2(VRM02)\" and {{item.ROLE}} == \"active\") or ({{item.NODE}} == \"ha1(VRM01)\" and {{item.ROLE}} == \"standby\") %}Ok{% else %}Failed{% endif %}\r\n{% endfor %}\r\n"}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the braces from the conditions, e.g.

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: |
          {% for item in fusionquery1 %}
          {% if (item.NODE == "ha2(VRM02)" and item.ROLE == "active") or
                (item.NODE == "ha1(VRM01)" and item.ROLE == "standby") %}
          Ok
          {% else %}
          Failed
          {% endif %}
          {% endfor %}
```

gives

```yaml
  msg: |-
    Ok
    Ok
```